# Linking entities to existing tables without code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's assume that we have java entities already implemented and annotated with Jpa annotations.

We also have an existing database slightly different to the schema described by said entities.

How I can link the data base with my entities without the code?

Otherwise, how can i proceed  from the begining when implementing my entities to make this stuff configurable ( give the user the possiblity of specifying the names of the columns corresponding to the fields of each entity in an externalized configuration file)?

NB:  I use hibernate as an ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank u @Petros Splinakis It's nearly what i need. Now how can I externalize the parameters of the configuratioh  that will be setted by the user in my own xml file of configuration ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. All you need is to provide a file named orm.xml with the configuration which you need to override. You may find the xsd for that file in http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html.